# "Using troughs in this way to identify particular bonds is covered on a separate page" - or "The use of.."?

Tags: style, gerund-clauses

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/analysis/ir/fingerprint.html#top):

> Note:  **Using** troughs in this way to identify particular bonds is covered on a separate page.

Wouldn't it be stylistically better to say

> Note:  **The use of** troughs in this way to identify particular bonds is covered on a separate page.

Or to say it in some other way that would get rid of "Using ... is covered"?

Or maybe this "using" is perfectly okay there?

Comment: It's colloquial.  *Using an app to start your car has just gotten a lot more secure now that mobile devices can read fingerprints.*

Comment: I find it preferable to "*The* use of troughs *in this way* to identify..."  not because there's anything wrong with **in this way** but my ear tells me that I don't want to modify "*the* use" with such a phrase.

Comment: It seems that chemists aren't too concerned about this level of style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TRomano said earlier, the first sentence is colloquial; it works only in informal or spoken English.  As such, it is sort of out of place in a chemistry book, but the author may have been trying to achieve a specific effect.  (Just look at *[Quantum Computing since Democritus](https://books.google.com/books?id=jRGfhSoFx0oC&printsec=frontcover&dq=quantum%20computing%20since%20democritus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi97-zE3bPMAhUFrB4KHagTDT0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=quantum%20computing%20since%20democritus&f=false)* for colloquial language being used in a highly academic book.)

What both phrases do is to turn a verb into a noun phrase.  However, "use" is actually the noun form of "to use" while "using" is just a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English).

**Bottom line: both are fine grammatically, but only the second is stylistically good.**